# Uninstall Ubuntu and Fix Windows MBR

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uninstall, mbr

I need to uninstall my Ubuntu from my personal machine (because I already have it in my work machine and my Windows is now more necessary with the personal).

I'd usually uninstall Ubuntu by deleting partitions that have no file system (in the disk management), and then boot my Windows recovery USB and use these:

```
BootRec.exe /FixMbr
BootRec.exe /FixBoot
```

However, this doesn't seem to work now. I deleted the partitions that look like Ubuntu, but wasn't able to boot into Windows again and only a black-screen grub appears. I reinstalled Ubuntu just so I can access Windows again.

What can I do to permanently remove Ubuntu and fix my MBR? Thanks!

Here's a screenshot of my disk partitions. It kinda' looks strange to me.

[image: disk partitions]

Comment: This is a windows problem, not one of Ubuntu. "permanently remove Ubuntu"  -- from Windows -- "and fix my MBR" -- from windows --.

Comment: IS this an EFI boot computer?

Comment: yes it is @ravery.

Comment: If it is EFI then do NOT apply methods for old BIOS. With UEFI you just select the EFI entry and it boots Windows directly. You may later  remove the Ubuntu entries but you don't have to, they don't prevent booting Windows, unlike with BIOS installs where only one bootloade could be installed in the MBR.

Comment: If I change the boot settings and put Windows first, will it work as I need to?